# Entity Framework Core DB first Mapping columns or tables into properties or class with different names

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-core-2.0

I use scaffolding after each schema change to keep in sync model and database.

I need to expose some columns with different name at domain level then the name at database level.

For example the column **COMPANY_NAME** in the table **COMPANY_PROFILE** at domain level needs to be changed in `WorkingCompany` and COMPANY_PROFILE be translated in the class `Company`

Moreover I don't want to lose any changes every time I run the scaffolding

Comment: Can't you do it the other way around and use migrations to do the DB changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CodeFirst configurations.

```
public class CompanyConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<Company>
{
   public CompanyConfiguration()
   {        
        this.ToTable("COMPANY_PROFILE");
        this.Property(p => p.WorkingCompany)
                .HasColumnName("COMPANY_NAME");
   }
 }
```